# how to split js functions into several files according to their types in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I am currently using vue.js for projects (not vue cli). I wrote all the functions in the same js file. I want to split these functions into several files according to their types. The js files are then imported into vue.js. Is there any way to do it? If I can’t, how can I change it to make this file easier to maintain in the future?

//I would like to import funtion from cart.js. Could I use the below method?

```
import shopping_cart from '/shopping_cart.js';
new Vue({
el: '#index',
data: {
message: 'test',
},
methods: {
    functionA(value) {
        //call function from shopping_cart.js
    }
}
})
```

Comment: are you using any bundler like webpack ?

Comment: @ashwin bande  No

Comment: then you cant `import`!, the vue cli setup webpack, a bundler which can handle import.

Comment: Is there any way to split js functions into several files in vue.js?